# TYPO3 responsive img datakey.xxx has no stdWrap?

Tags: image-processing, typo3, typo3-6.2.x, responsive-images, srcset

I want to get specific image info in the sourcecollection:
if original imagewidth < 1040px it should give a datakey which has the original width,
so I tried to get the original width

```
maxW < TSFE:lastImageInfo|0
```

and other differnet methods, but it seems it only catches Labels not the values.
see example "small".
TSRef says width, maxW ... has stdWrap capabillities, so how can I get the values?

```
tt_content.image.20.1.sourceCollection {
    small >
    smallRetina >


    smallest {

        width = 320
        maxW.cObject = TEXT
        maxW.cObject.value = 4444
        dataKey = smallest
        srcsetCandidate = 320
        elementwidth = 320
    }
    smallest.maxW < TSFE:lastImageInfo|0 // gets null


    smaller {
        width = 480
        if.isLessThan = 439
        if.value.data = TSFE:lastImageInfo|0
        testparm = testp
        maxW < TSFE:lastImageInfo|0 //gets null
        dataKey = smaller
        srcsetCandidate = 480
        elementwidth = 480
    }

    small {
        stdWrap.cObject = COA
        stdWrap.cObject {
            10 = LOAD_REGISTER
            10.intobj2 = COA
            10.intobj2 {
               10 = TEXT
               10.data = TSFE:lastImageInfo|0

            }
            20 = TEXT
            20.insertData = 1
            20.data = ghj

       }
       width = 720
        if.isLessThan = 719
        if.value.data = TSFE:lastImageInfo|0
        maxW = 720
        dataKey = small
        maxW.insertData = 1
        maxW.stdWrap.insertData = 1
        maxW.stdWrap.cObject < .stdWrap.cObject.20 // gets "TEXT"!!!
        srcsetCandidate = 720
        elementwidth = 720
    }


    ...

    realSizePic {
        width.data = TSFE:lastImageInfo|0
        maxW.data = TSFE:lastImageInfo|0
        maxW.cObject = TEXT
        maxW.cObject.value = testrealsize
        #mediaQuery = (min-width: 1100px)
        dataKey = biggest
        srcsetCandidate.stdWrap.data = TSFE:lastImageInfo|0
        /* doesn'T work!!!
        srcsetCandidate.cObject = TEXT
        srcsetCandidate.cObject {
            data = TSFE:lastImageInfo|0
        }
        */
        elementwidth.data = TSFE:lastImageInfo|0

    }
}
```

- will be rendered as srcset

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.data` in `maxW` when you want to use registred values. In your if condition you have used `.data` correctly...

```
maxW.data = TSFE:lastImageInfo|0
```

Comment: yes, but regardless of using 
maxW.cObject = TEXT
maxW.value = XXX

or
maxW.data = TSFE:lastImageInfo|0

or 
maxW < someObject

it only accepts Strings and if pointing to an object I get the name of the object, even when setting maxW.insertData = 1

Comment: If you first set `maxW.cObject` and then overwrite it with `smallest.maxW < TSFE:lastImageInfo|0` it will not work. `smallest.maxW >` and `smallest.maxW.data = TSFE:lastImageInfo|0` would be the correct way.

Comment: yes, I did try a lot of different ways, which I forgot to erase, but my problem is that it only workes with setting to string not  using getData,
  
smallest {  
        width = 320  
        maxW.cObject = TEXT  
        maxW.cObject.value = 4444 // -> null     
    }  
#